# If $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent, then $f(X)$ is almost surely constant

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Reading some exam material, I found this property:

Let $f :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ a measurable function. If $X$ and $f(X)$ are independent, then $f(X)$ is almost surely constant.

Most of the properties come with a proof, but this one doesn't. So I assume that it's trivial, but I just can't see it. Any thoughts?

Comment: "$f$ is almost surely constant" doesn't make sense.  You mean
$f(X)$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event  $f(X) \le a$.  Then $A$ is independent of itself (if random variables $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, then the events $Y \in B$ and
$Z \in C$ are independent, for any measurable sets $B$ and $C$).  Now what can you say
about an event that is independent of itself?

Comment: It's probability is 1?

Comment: Or possibly zero. Solutions to $x^2=x$.

Comment: I get now why this implies that there is only one a such that $f(X) \le a$. But why is A independent of itself?

Comment: I mean $f(X) = a$.

Comment: Let $B=\{\omega | f(X(\omega)) \in (\infty,a]\}$ and $C = (\infty,a]$. Then $X \in B$ and $F(X) \in C$ are the same event, but by assumption of independence, $p(B \cap C) = pB pC$, or equivalently, $pB = (p B)^2$.

Comment: Thank you, cooper.hat and Robert.