# Independence of solution to SDE and initial condition

Tags: solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $(\Omega,F,(F_t)_{t\geq 0},P)$ be a filtered probability space with the standard condition.
Let $W_t$ be the $F_t$-Wiener process, and
let $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}\subset {\mathbb{R}}$ be the (strong) solution of the SDE
$$
X_t = X_0 + \int _0^t b(X_s,s)ds + \int_0^t \sigma(X_s,s)dW_s,
$$
where the initial condition $X_0$ is $F_0$-measurable.

Is it true that $X_t$ ($t>0$) and $X_0$ are independent?
The argument in [Independence of Solution of SDE $S^{(x_0, \sigma, \mu)}_t$ of Initial Information $\mathcal{G}_0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211075/independence-of-solution-of-sde-sx-0-sigma-mu-t-of-initial-informatio) seems to say that they are.

Comment: Definition $1.6$ of chapter $4$ in Ikeda-Watanabe's book (Stochastic differential equations and diffusion processes) states that a strong solution is a measurable function of the Brownian motion and the initial condition, so it seems to me that the independence cannot hold

Comment: Sorry but could you elaborate why so it seems?

Comment: I suspect this argument could work https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289190/if-x-and-fx-are-independent-then-fx-is-almost-surely-constant

Comment: I don't really see how the result quoted is applicable. Fix $t$. What Ikeda-Watanabe require would imply is that 
$\mathbb{R}\times \Omega \ni (x,\omega)\mapsto X_t(x,\omega)\in \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, and thus 
for $F_0/{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable ininial condition $X_0$, the mapping
 $\omega \mapsto (X_0(\omega),\omega)\mapsto  X_t(X_0(\omega),\omega)$ will be $F_0/B(\mathbb{R})$-measurable. But now the function $f$ in the quoted result also depends on $\omega$, which is a situation more general than the link, is it not?